# LyX: Install quantikz package

Tags: lyx, packages, installing

I'm running Ubuntu and use LyX for my work.

I want to use the `quantikz` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz?lang=en .

I added

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
```

to my preamble but I get the following error:

```
Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'quantikz'. I looked for 

\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
```

How do I install `quantikz` on my system?

Comment: Hi and welcome. In order for `LyX` to work, a `LateX` distribution must first be installed. Have you installed `TexLive` or `MikTeX`? On MikTeX, you have to go to the management console and ask it to install `quantikz`. On TexLive, I don't know.

Comment: I have TexLive installed.

Comment: if you have texlive from tug then `tlmgr install quantikz` is all you need  if you have a linux repackaged texlive that may work or you may need to use apt-get or yum or whatever your linux uses

Comment: Ok, I was able to install the package with the new 2020 version of TexLive.

Comment: Now, answer your own question yourself as shown here  : [Can I answer my own question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)